# Is this part of the Banach density function $BD$ subadditive?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, functions

Let $A$ be a set and consider the function $$f(n) = \max_{x \in \mathbb{Z}} |A \cap [x+1,x+n]|,$$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I am reading a paper "An elementary proof of Jin’s theorem with a bound" by Mauro Di Nasso and in the footnotes of the second page it makes the claim that $f$ is subadditive. I cannot seem to get this conclusion, it is obvious that $f(n) \leq f(m)$ when $n \leq m$, but this is the best I can do. Here is my work towards subadditivity:

$$f(n+m) = \max_{x \in \mathbb{Z}} |A \cap [x+1,x+n+m]| = \max_{x \in \mathbb{Z}} |A \cap ([x+1,x+n] \cup (x+n,x+n+m])| \\ \leq \max_{x \in \mathbb{Z}} |A \cap[x+1,x+n]| + \max_{x \in \mathbb{Z}} |A \cap(x+n,x+n+m]|.$$ I do not know how to continue from here. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're so close. Think about what the final term in your calculation is calculating. Maybe write $x'=x+n$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe: I see, the last term is calculating the largest number of elements of $A$ in an interval of length $m$. So we can make the substitution that you mentioned and be done.